# UITableView is laggy when scrolling up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

> Solution: Use SDWebImage: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

I have a UITableView which becomes very laggy when during scrolling. I discovered the lag appears when the image that I am using is coming back on the screen.

I am using a custom UITableViewCell. Is this also a reason why it's lagging?

My custom UITableViewCell:

[image]

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];


tableViewCellActiviteiten *cell = (tableViewCellActiviteiten *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableViewCellActiviteiten" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (tableViewCellActiviteiten *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}


cell.thetitle.text = [self.alletitels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.thesubtitle.text = [self.allesubtitels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString * imagePath = [self.alleimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.image.image = image;

return cell;
```

}

Content of the arrays:

`self.alletitels` contains a string: "Activity Title"

`self.allesubtitels` contains a string: "Activity Subtitle"

`self.alleimages` contains a url: "http://m2.myhappygames.com//files/pics/0/Paranormal_Shark_Activity_3.jpg"

Can anyone advise what might be the cause of the laggy scrolling?

Comment: You are lagging because you are getting the image from the net.  You may want to try getting the image asynchronously from another dispatch queue. Look up grand central dispatch.

Comment: This is a classic anti-pattern and a very common programming faux pas.  This question is asked about 10 times a week. Using the search feature might have revealed dozens of solutions.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I understand, but I still can't found an answer and I fixed it for a part, but the tableview stays laggy. Really frustrating...

Comment: When caching images, you should ensure that the image is also _decoded_ (having a bitmap by drawing into a context) and that its current size fits perfectly within the UIImage's frame. You need to ensure that this is the case immediately _before_ the cell is drawn. So, possibly, you need a more sophisticated caching strategy. None of the mentioned helper libraries will do that for you, though.

Comment: I have the same problem when load the item from database and dynamic font size and dynamic cell size implementing?

Comment: @AlbinJoseph I fixed it with the EGO frameworks: https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading and https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that every time `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is called your code generates an image. This will be called each time a cell appears on the screen, therefore if you scroll really fast this method will start allocating a lot of images synchronously which will slow down the scroll.

As a fast solution, implement NSCache in your View Controller and store images in it.

```
UIImage *image = [_imageCache objectForKey:@indexPath.row];
if (image == nil) {
    NSString * imagePath = [self.alleimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [_imageCache setObject:image forKey:@indexPath.row];
}

cell.image.image = image;
```

_imageCahce is an instance variable of view controller that you can implement.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: "As a fast solution, implement NSCache in your View Controller and store images in it." I'm very new to NSCache.. how to store the images in NSCache? And should I still use the self.alleimages array?

Comment: In a few words, NSCache behaves almost exactly the same as NSDictionary, but has less functionality. You store images in NSCache exactly the same way as with NSDictionary (setObject: forKey: method). And yes - you will still need your self.alleimages array to retrieve the URLs. Here is the link to AppleDocs on NSCache https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Ok thanks! The forKey that you use is:@indexPath.row. Do you mean @"indexPath.row" as a string or the code itself indexPath.row? I made a @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSCache *imageCache; and now I have to use: [imageCache setObject:@"http://m2.myhappygames.com//files/pics/0/Paranormal_Shark_Activity_3.jpg" forKey:@"images"]; and retrieve it with your code above?

Comment: @indexPath.row is an object literal. It is essentially this - [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]. And I don't think you can have NSCache as an IBOutlet, as there is no interface element that is responsible for NSCache. And finally, yes, my code should work, but it is a fast solution.

Comment: Thanks! Do you got Skype or mail? I would like to send you some code what I did. And maybe you can see where it goes wrong. If you can help me out I will set this answer +1 and an accepted answer green sign. :)

Comment: Man, this community is for everyone to share their knowledge and experience. If you want for us to take a look at your code, just post it to your update. No need to bribe anyone :)

Comment: I understand! I was asking it because I felt a little bit ashamed of posting my code that doesn't work. I just can't get the NSCache going to work and don't know what to do else... It looks like NSCache is making my UITableView more slower...

Comment: I have an email in my profile in case you want to figure it out.

Comment: I can't find you mail on your profile. I made a new project just for you so you can see what I did in my code. I would like to send the project to you, but can't seem to find your mail...

Comment: The only problem with this solution is, that it wont work ;)  You need to load images asynchronously and possibly save them into a cache. If there is no image, display a placeholder. The completion block of the async loader must check whether the cell is visible. If so, set the image, otherwise do nothing. When the image cache gets exhausted, you need a more sophisticated cache that holds only a few images but _preloads_ and _prepares_ the images *ahead*. That way, whenever any cell is about to be drawn, the image is already prepared and renders quickly.

Comment: What is the preferred mechanism to check if a given cell (or image) is visible?

Answer (score 6):

These two lines here:

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Are what is dramatically slowing down your table performance.

You're doing synchronous fetching and loading of image data *every time* you refresh that cell.

It would be smarter to somehow cache (or save locally) the images to be displayed.  And if they aren't saved locally or in a cache, only then go fetch those images (and do that asychronously, outside of that "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method).

Comment: I'm using NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest to get the image urls from my json data. After that I save the urls in a NSMutableArray. How to save the urls in the cache?

Comment: You're getting the image URL's and saving them into a mutable array, that's nice.  What's *even better* is if you use sendAsynchronousRequest to fetch the actual images and then save those UIImages in a mutableArray.

Answer (score 4):

You are making synchronous network calls to download the images while cell is getting created. These calls block the main thread until the image for cell downloads. Lag time will vary based on the quality of network.

The solution for this is use of technique called "Lazy loading". In this technique image loading will take place on a separate thread, thus unblocking the main thread. Image is downloaded and then applied to the correct container `UIImageView`. Here is [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) for lazy loading of images in table view.

You can also use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). This will do image caching for you as well.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Along with caching you may also consider loading the images in background using Grand central dispatch. When the cell is loaded put a UIActivityIndicator then replace it with an image in a separate thread.

```
// get a data provider referencing the relevant file
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filename);

// use the data provider to get a CGImage; release the data provider
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, 
                                                kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

// make a bitmap context of a suitable size to draw to, forcing decode
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
unsigned char *imageBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(width*height*4);

CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef imageContext =
CGBitmapContextCreate(imageBuffer, width, height, 8, width*4, colourSpace,
              kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

// draw the image to the context, release it
CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
CGImageRelease(image);

// now get an image ref from the context
CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContext);

// post that off to the main thread, where you might do something like
// [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputImage]
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(haveThisImage:) 
     withObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:outputImage] waitUntilDone:YES];

// clean up
CGImageRelease(outputImage);
CGContextRelease(imageContext);
free(imageBuffer);
```

You can also use UIImage+ImmediateLoad.m
  It decodes images immediately. Besides UIImage -initWithContentsOfFile:, -imageWithCGImage: and CG* are thread-safe after iOS4.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load images on the same UI thread where you are scrolling. You should load them to cache in the background and then get from cache when they are ready to show.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, I examined it with Profiler, so here are a few tought:

1) You are using wrong the Reuseable Indentifier, you should always use the same identifier.

instead of this:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
```

use this:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
```

for more read on: [how to use UItableViewCell reuseIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378522/how-to-use-uitableviewcell-reuseidentifier)

2) loadNibNamed method is really slow ( plus you are loading it each time for every cell), you should get rid of the nib, and place the UI elements from code by overwriteing this method of an UITableViewCell

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

3) use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are making a synchronous network call for each image Thats whay you are getting lag in your app. Try [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)
 it will download your images from web Asynchronously . And You will be able to remove the lag from your app. :-)