# Is it possible to have custom TableViewCells with different contents, using reuseIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a TableView with up to 50 cells in it which contain 5 subviews containing common information (title, description, price...) and 5 optional subviews (offer price, offer expiry...). These are built by adding everything then hiding optional views that are not appropriate to that cell.

Using a common `reuseIdentifier` meant that all cells were layed-out the same as the last cell built and cached. So initially I've gone with using `reuseIdentifier:nil` and it works, but it seems like a bad performance hit to rebuild these every single time they're displayed. Some could be reused across cells as there are <5! variants but this could be tricky to maintain, so I'd be happier if I could cache them all individually at least.

I've experimented with `reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long) indexPath.row]` but get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell 
with identifier 1 - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or 
connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I can't figure out how to initialise the TableView with `[self.tableView registerClass:... forCellReuseIdentifier:...]` to allow this, but others have used this or a simlar approach so what am I missing?

[Custom UITableViewCell with reuseIdentifier without Style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729612/custom-uitableviewcell-with-reuseidentifier-without-style)

[how to use UItableViewCell reuseIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378522/how-to-use-uitableviewcell-reuseidentifier)

I'm working with an inherited project with just a few days of experience in obj-C and picking up a few horrors, so this whole approach could be suspect. And all views are done programmatically. I can add code snippets if required.

Cheers!

Comment: you can create 5 different type of cell for 5 variants, and can cache and maintain them by using different reusable identifers. but it leads to code more and you will have more views and classes in the end.

Comment: Implement `prepareForReuse` in your cell's class implementation.  If you don't have a `UITableVewCell` subclass for your cells, well now you will :)

Comment: @Avi - on reading up on this, it's used to 'reset' the cell to as it would be if initWithStyle had been called on it, but with less overhead, so that means I can use a static reuseIdentifier? I'll explore more, but will wait for an answer on how to use the 'one reuseIdentifier for each cell' approach.

Comment: @IrfanGul - yeah, it would get messy and I think this is my least-favourite option. One to ticket for a future date maybe, but I need to pick the low-hanging fruit for now and get this app working.

Comment: check second approach, I do it more often. :)

Comment: @Avi - that's working, so thanks for the pointer to `prepareForReuse`. If you add as a full answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `prepareForReuse` in your cell's class implementation.  Reset the views to their default state.  In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, configure the cell as needed for the particular data it is to display.

Comment: That worked, and is clearly caching but not breaking layout so this looks like the best workable solution for me for now. Though still unsure how to do this where the reuseIdentifier changes for each row and not sure which would give the better performance.

Comment: If the reuseIndentifier changes for each row, it's not really being reused :)

Comment: In testing, I logged the object reference for the cells when using reuseIdentifier:nil and it seemed that when a cell was scrolled off the screen, then scrolled back into view, the cell had a new object reference. This suggested to me that they were being rebuilt when an existing object could have been dequeued with the reuseIdentifier set to the indexPath.row. I could be mistaken, or completely wrong as this is all very new to me right now.

Comment: Having one reusable cell per row is technically reusing cells, but it's definitely not the intent.  Most table views use a very small selection of cell types (commonly 1), but use many of them as the user scrolls.

Comment: I can see I may be confusing the change in cell object reference as an absence of reuse of dequeued, styled cells. Anyway, thanks for explaining and I think that's me done on this as it's working fine and I have much more to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

**One solution** to the problem is to use separate `UITableViewCell` Class and `Reusable Identifier` for each Variant of Cell. But it leads to code more and gets messy to manage and do changes if needed.

**Second Solution** is to use a single `UITableViewCell` subclass and Single `Reusable Identifier`.

Now you need to distinguish between cell types for this create `enum` for `TableViewCellType` .

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TableCellType) {
    TableCellTypeOfferPrice,
    TableCellTypeExpiry,
    TableCellTypeXYZ
};
```

add property in your `UITableViewCell` Subclass.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) TableCellType cellType;
```

Create a method in `UITableViewCell` Subclass.

`-(void)setupUIWithCellType:(TableCellType)cellType`

In this method you can setup UI elements according to cell type by using `switch cases`. You can hide unnecessary view here, adjust frames of subviews etc.

Now in DataSource Method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do like this.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
        //Call to setupUIWithCellType
        [cell setupUIWithCellType:dataArray[indexpath.row]];
        return cell;
}
```

This approach makes Controller class cleaner and all necessary code lies in TableViewCell subclass in a good way.

Comment: I have one BookTableCell and another InfoTableCell, and separating between the two uses a similar approach to what you've described above. With BookTableCells we might have variants such as "common subviews with subview A", 'common subviews with subview B", "common subviews with A and B", "common subviews with C", "common subviews with A and C", etc... There are 5 optional subviews and although it's unlikely that we will have one of every variation, I can see us having >10. Not something I want to juggle, and the approach suggested by @Avi is working